# Having trouble assigning values to arrays and printing them to console

Tags: c, arrays

Hey I am having trouble assigning values to an array using C and then simply printing them. I feel like I'm going crazy and something this simple should be easy but I can't spot the error for the life of me. Any help would be grealty appreciated. I dont get any output when i try compile and run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int dice_rolls[77];

int main(void) {


    dice_rolls[0] = 1;

    printf("%d", dice_rolls[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a newline to the end of the printf. You may not be seeing the output because it's on the same line as your shell prompt.

Comment: It works fine: http://ideone.com/mDnw3F

Comment: Change `"%d"` to `"%d\n"`.  That way the output will appear on its own line, rather than in front of your next command prompt.